# Direct list initialization or direct initialization in member initializer list?

Tags: c++, initialization, member-initialization

I recently caught up  on **Member Initializer Lists**.
The [Cpp-Learning-Site](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/variable-assignment-and-initialization/) suggests to always prefer direct list initialization over direct initilization.

```cpp
int a(5);
int b{5};    // preferred
```

I noticed that both of these can be used in Member initializer lists.

Which one of the following is better and for which reasons?
Thank you in advance.

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    int a;
    Foo(int a): a(a) {}
};

class Bar {
public:
    int a;
    Bar(int a): a{a} {}
};
```

Comment: I usually use the list initialization to disallow narrowing. Also, if you use list initialization you wont run in to the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Of course, you can't always use list initialization, like for example if you're trying to call one of `std::vector`'s overloaded constructors.

Comment: [Good discussion (among the other wisdom found in the Core Guidelines)](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax)